# simplest way to redeploy gwt application running in user personal gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, gwt, deployment

If our gwt application is deployed to user's own GAE instance, what's the optimal way to update it regularly?
For the first deployment user can send us his gae login/password and we will deploy application from developer eclipse or maven and user will change the password then.
But such scheme will be very inconvenient for further bug-fixes, version updates and so on.

Common way is to write some kind of installator program which user runs on own machine, prompts his google credentials there and it will deploy/update with standart google maven script.

Are there any means in GAE for that? (or can gae application update itself?) May be any good third-party or open-source soft?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of mechanisms you might want to consider, depending upon how technical your customer is.

One idea: Your customer could give you developer permissions via the GAE console at appengine.google.com (Administration -> Permissions).  Then you could just update the code as needed.

Another idea: Set up some sort of version control system for the code, e.g. Subversion or git or whatever you are using.  You could make the code changes, commit them, and then your customer would update and deploy themselves.  (Of course, they will have to learn how to do that, but perhaps it could be scripted via the command-line tool appcfg.)

Comment: Also see Nick's answer, if the same app code is going to support multiple customers.

Comment: thanks, considering the [nature of app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014389/simplest-way-to-redeploy-gwt-application-running-in-user-personal-gae/8031578#8031578), I think only fist idea is valid ("customer could give you developer permissions via the GAE console").
Another way is writing kind of installator/updater program.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is not to do this in the first place - use App Engine's multitenancy support to isolate data for different users in a single app.

If you must deploy separate apps, sign up for a premier account under the new billing model, which will let you create an unlimited number of apps. You can then add the customer as a viewer/developer/owner as appropriate (and restrict your own permissions as appropriate) on the created app.

Comment: the application will store personal user finance data, so I doubt that a lot of customers will want to run it on developer gae instance, where a developer will be able to have a full access to his data.

Comment: @yetanothercoderu But as the author of the app, you could have any access you want just by including a backdoor - users already have to trust you. And in order to be able to deploy apps using a premier account, you'll have to be an admin, which gives you datastore access anyway.

Comment: true, but in case of single developer gae instance for all clients - we'll have to pay for gae anycase (lot's of traffic, space etc.), whereas in case of user personal gae - a free account will be enough for each and nobody will have to pay =)

Comment: @yetanothercoderu Which is why you'll need a premier account if you want to do this. Free quota is provided to make it easy for developers to get started on App Engine - not to subsidize your business model.